# Django - Connecting to existing RDS postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make a Django app to connect to an existing RDS postgres instance

I have changed my `settings.py` file to the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': <db-name>,
        'USER': <username>,
        'PASSWORD': <pswd>,
        'HOST': 'project-hash.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

After creating Django project, running `python manage.py migrate` yelds:

```
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gustavo.figueiredo/anaconda3/envs/lp_admin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "auth_permission" already exists
```

Comment: Does "./manage.py migrate" work as expected with a local Postgres server ? I suspect it does not work too.

Comment: it did in a previous attempt. I created the postgres db locally and set it up, before trying to connect to the remote one

Comment: What's in the existing RDS instance? Does it already contain tables and data? And how do these relate to the django app you're trying to connect?

Comment: @dirkgroten I have a web2py application with a large database and I just wanted to use the same DB for a new django app

Comment: Then you should use create a new database in the same RDS. You can’t use the same database. (`NAME` should be different)

Comment: and then import the data from one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "auth_permission" already exists

You do not have a problem connecting.  To get this error, you must already be connected.

The problem is that the migration you are trying to run is incompatible with the database you are connected to.

Comment: this answered my original question

Answer (score 3):

`manage.py migrate` will always fail if it tries to run a migration and finds that any action it's attempting to perform -- in this case, create a table to store user permission data -- has already been done.

If the database instance already exists, you would be much better served [making use of `manage.py inspectdb` to create models from the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/), rather than using `manage.py migrate` to apply models to the database.

If your database is an existing Django database, and you're looking to just get the migrations up and running, [the simplest way is to run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake-initial) to mark the migration as having been applied without actually performing any database operations other than bumping the migration version.

Comment: what if my database is not an existing Django database? in my case specifically, I have a web2py app currently working with this database